# What does "group_close" mean in Slack's Event Webhooks?

Tags: slack-api

When using the Events Webhook API, there is an event called `group_close` (also has `im_close` for im conversations). What does this mean? ie: what does it take on the Slack client to get this event to trigger? Slack's documentation on this is pretty minimal:

`The group_close event is sent to all connections for a user when a private channel is closed by that user.`

source: https://api.slack.com/events/group_close

I tried `/close` command and it just archives the group/im conversation. Is this an outdated event that is no longer relevant? I know it still gets called, but as far as I can tell, it's identical to archive.

Answer (score 0):

The `group_close` events refers to a multi-person DM (this should be corrected in the documentation). You can close an MPDM and trigger the event by clicking the `x` next to the conversation on side bar or running the `/close` slash command like you did. This doesn't actually archive the channel just removes it from your sidebar. You should be able to re-open it.